# Howto: Make bibliography with bracket numbers and referencing them by numbers

Tags: asciidoctor

The basic bibliography in Asciidoctor works with names, but not with automatic numbering.

I would like to have a bibliography and a usage of it like:

```
They say, this is a title[1] and it's pretty nice[2].

[1] This is my title bla
    bla bla bla bla and 
    more text, 2005
[2] lalalalalalalalalala
    blabla, 2005 - 2006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution brings the following output:

## Output

[image]

## Code

They say, this is a title<> and it's pretty nice<>.

```
== References
[[references]]
[cols="1d,98"]
|===

| [[ref_title, &#91;{counter:bibliNr}&#93;]] <<ref_title>>
| My first reference dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd

| [[ref_nice, &#91;{counter:bibliNr}&#93;]] <<ref_nice>>
| My second reference, 2004 - 2009

|===
```

## Explanation

- `[cols="1d,98"]`: Says, that the the first column has a width of 1% and the second one of 98%. the `d` means, that macros and stuff are actually executed. This is necessary for the counters.
- `&#91;` and `&#93;` are equal to `[` and `]` respectively. It's at least necessary to use `&#93;`. Otherwise the interpreter gets confused with all the brackets.
- `{counter:bibliNr}`: This is the syntax for a counter. [Details here](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#counters)
- `[[ref_title, &#91;{counter:bibliNr}&#93;]] <<ref_title>>`: The first part (within brackets) defines the actual reference and determines the counter number. The `<<ref_title>>` is simply a link to the first part. So it shows the number